# Deselecting the list item activated and activating the other one by default using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am having the list of categories present in my website.Written jquery code for that to deselect the category if the user clicks on that list category for second time.Once the user clicks on the selected category it should be deselected and All button  category should be selected by default.

AS of now if i click on the selected category for second time it is deselecting that category but the all button is not selecting by default.

Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
    jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.tribe-events-category-5 {
  background-color: #800000;
  border-left: 5px solid #800000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li class="tribe-events-category-all"><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you want to do not clearly undestand

Comment: @Bhargav as of now when i open a web page by default it will be selected as music if i click for the second time the music tab will be deselected.Once it is deselected All tab should be selected by default

Comment: you must add the code for the tabs too that you are referring to .

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam not getting you what you are saying

Comment: all other li color change or what effect do after

Comment: @Bhargav if i click the activated one for second time it will be deactivated and at that time only All should be activated

Comment: its very confusing your question

Comment: @Bhargav as of now music is selected by default right if i click on the same active tab it will be deselected.And none of the tabs are selected but i need All should be selected if there no tabs selected then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you were expecting for or not. Just take a look into it. Here is a fiddle with your  code but has been edited a little and one more thing instead of using jQuery all the time you can use $ instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");

$("#legend li").on("click", function(){    
$("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
if($("#legend li").hasClass("active")){
$(".tribe-events-category-all").addClass("active");
}else{
$(".tribe-events-category-all").removeClass("active");
}
 $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {   
opacity: 0.3;
}
.tribe-events-category-5{
background-color: #800000;
border-left: 5px solid #800000;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.4em;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#legend li{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
<li class="tribe-events-category-all"><span>All</span></li>
<li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
<li><span>Dance</span></li>
<li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it by finding class for `All` and toggle it using `jQuery(this).prev('.tribe-events-category-all').toggleClass("active");`  like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function(){ 
jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
if(!$(this).hasClass("tribe-events-category-all") && !$(this).hasClass("active")){
jQuery(this).siblings('.tribe-events-category-all').toggleClass("active");
}
});
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {   
opacity: 0.3;
}
.tribe-events-category-5{
background-color: #800000;
border-left: 5px solid #800000;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.4em;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#legend li{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
<li class="tribe-events-category-all"><span>All</span></li>
<li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
<li><span>Dance</span></li>
<li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Ashalatha Check my answer and see if it meets the requirements

Comment: No its not working by default music is highlighted right if i click music again it will be deselected at that time All should be highlighted,in the same way if if i select the other one without deselecting music the one which i selected should be highlighted and music should be deselected

Comment: The code which you have written is if i select the other tabs like Dance or Festivals etc the previous selected or not getting deselected

Comment: All button is selected only if music is deselected then if not it is not working

Comment: @Ashalatha I just updated it again now all will be active when you have not selected anything from any other option. If you select any other option then All will not be active. Let me know if it meets your requirement :)